# Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to connect MongoDB Atlas with Java. This is my code

```
MongoClientSettings.Builder mongoClientSettingsBuilder = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .credential(mongoCredential)
        .applyToClusterSettings(builder -> builder.hosts(new ServerAddress("dev-20937-liwy3.gcp.mongodb.net", 27017)));
MongoClientSettings settings = mongoClientSettingsBuilder.build();      
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
```

By doing so I am getting the following error

```
INFO: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Mar 26, 2020 11:33:41 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=dev-20937-liwy3.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: dev-20937-liwy3.gcp.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: dev-20937-liwy3.gcp.mongodb.net}}]
```

I do not know the cause of the error. By my guess I have given my host name wrong.

Can someone help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

go to your `MongoDB Atlas` -> `NetworkAccess`-> Edit-> and add `Current IP address` it works!!

```
// Create a Mongo client 
  MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 ); 

  // Creating Credentials 
  MongoCredential credential; 
  credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("User", "DB", 
     "pass".toCharArray()); 
  System.out.println("Connected to the database successfully");
```

Comment: I have already whitelisted my IP. But still it throws the same error.

Comment: Did you select `Java` Driver in `MongoDB` Atlas?

Comment: In the home page where it shows all the clusters created, I navigated to Connect->Connect your application->java-> and got the link. It showed a URI which I used as `MongoClients.create(<link>)` doing this it got connected, but for customising some settings I am using MongoClientSettings, it is not getting connected with it though

Comment: Thank you. But actually I want to use MongoClientSettings for some customisation of connection settings like timeout settings etc.

Comment: Okay https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/  you can have a look

Comment: Thank You.. I have a doubt.. what should I give as host should it be "localhost" or "<..>.mongodb.net". If it is localhost how will I connect to a cluster that is not local?

Comment: `localhost` is the default name available for the loopback IP address (127.0.0.1) and should always be defined. Your computer also has a unique `hostname` defined. You  can check in your `MongoDB` shell `getHostName()`

Comment: when I use getHostName() it returns as `MyPC.local`. If I connect to a remote cluster should I give `<..>.mongodb.net` as hostName parameter in MongoClient?

Comment: For many applications, you need to have `MongoClient` instance for the `JVM`   
`MongoClient mongoclient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost"));`
` MongoClient mongoclient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);`
`MongoClient mongoclient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost"), MongoClientOptions.builder().build());` you can use any of them  running on the default `port`

Comment: When I connect to MongoShell or use `MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(<URI>)` I use the connection string `mongodb+srv://dev-20937-liwy3.gcp.mongodb.net/test` does this mean this `dev-20937-liwy3.gcp.mongodb.net`  is my hostName? this should be used instead of localhost. is my question

Comment: If you have installed `MongoDB` on your computer then `MongoClient mongo client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);`  this will work. But you are trying for connection to `MongoDB Atlas` so, `MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://dev-20937-liwy3.gcp.mongodb.net/test");` both are different

Comment: So this means that if its not local we should use only MongoClientURI and not other approaches?

Comment: Thanks alot. That will help